# Is there way to convert straight horizontal bar into angled one?

Tags: hardware, sports

There are straight horizontal chin-up bars and ones with angled ends. Could we use something to convert conventional horizontal bar into 2nd type? May be attach something to the ends.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Visit a plumber with a pipe bender, an electrician with a conduit bender, or a machine shop with a hydraulic press, or a home renovation centre for a pipe bender to fit the bar you have.

It will take you longer to take your bar to the tradesman than it will take to bend the bar.

You can buy or rent what you need to do the job if you want to do the job yourself.

Don't forget to figure-in the cost of the modification to the cost of the unit. It might be cheaper in the long run to buy what you need instead of one that requires a conversion.

Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Why not make your own? All you need is some pipe at the hardware store and two 45 degree elbow joints like this one:

[image: Source: www.pvcfittingsonline.com]

Connect this to each end of your pipe and then attach two smaller pipes as grips on the ends.

You can find all of this cheaply in the hardware store plumbing section.

Comment: I'm not sure that solvent drain plastic would be an effective material for what it is implied the op wants to do (create a pull up bar). Also, the diameter of waste pipe is likely too large to be gripped comfortably for extended periods of this kind of exercise

Comment: @CaiusJard If you google "pvc pullup bar" there's actually quite a few examples online. Of course, the OP can also you metal pipe if they want to.

Comment: Also you can get any diameter from of pipe you want like 1, 1.5 or 2 inch pipe.

Comment: While I don't doubt that PVC pull-up bars exist, I doubt they are made of household waste pipe..

Comment: @CaiusJard Example: https://www.artofmanliness.com/articles/how-to-build-the-ultimate-bodyweight-gym-using-only-pvc-pipe/ - If you don't like PVC, then use steel pipe instead.